# Dynamic Javascript condition in For loop

Tags: javascript

Please review the code below, note the condition of my for loop depends on the `step` parameter.

Rather than every time the condition is executed it determines which branch to use, I would like to test that once - I had supposed I could create a delegate or of the condition but it doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible in JS to do this?

Code:

```
function(start, end, step) {
  if (step === undefined) {
    step = 1;
  }

  var result = [];
  for (; (step < 0) ? start >= end : start <= end; start += step) {
    result.push(start);
  }

  return result;
}
```

My attempt:

```
function(start, end, step) {
  if (step === undefined) {
    step = 1;
  }

  var condition = (step < 0) ? start >= end : start <= end;
  var result = [];
  for (; condition; start += step) {
    result.push(start);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: That won't work since the condition is evaluated before `start` is ever changed. A hack way would be to define each as a function instead. There's definitely a better way though. I'll walk on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to make `condition` a function, like below. But even if you do, the condition is still executed at every iteration of the loop.

```
  var condition = (step < 0) ?
      function(start){
          return start >= end;
      } :
      function(start){
          return start <= end;
      };
  var result = [];
  for (; condition(start); start += step) {
    result.push(start);
  }
```